# Doctrine Data-Fixtures - OrmPurger - Missing table in delete

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony

[FixtureAwareTestCase](https://gist.github.com/a-ast/c07a2456fcb4bf4f7a947bff40c25366)

I'm currently using this class to load fixture for my unit tests.

It's working fine on my Windows/Wamp64/PHP7.0 setup, but on my Test server (Linux/Apache/PHP7.0), it's not working.

I'm looking in my log (test.log) and I can see that some tables don't have any "DELETE FROM *".

I've already tried to change my ManyToOne/OneToMany/ManyToMany's property targetEntity with complete namespace. But it didn't change anything.

I'm kind of clueless on this one. Thx.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, the tables are not cleared?

Comment: Not all the tables are cleared. They are some missing. Like I have a Client table with a FK to user and I don't have a "DELETE FROM users;" before "DELETE FROM clients".

Comment: it sounds very strange that it would be working on your wamp setup but not linux. Is there any chance the schema is not up to date?